# Prevent "Screen" session weird characters

Tags: arch-linux, gnu-screen

Logged into a screen session, when I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, or <kbd>Right</kbd> while there is nothing for those keys to do, then a weird character appears that does not affect the input.

The terminal does not see that they are there, when the command is entered. Is there any fix for this ? These characters should not exist.

Here is an example of the weird character, repeated several times.

[image: Weird Characters]

EDIT: I've got "KEYMAP=us" in my /etc/vconsole.conf.  Note: This is only displayed, but does not actually "exist". Meaning, it cannot be interacted with, and the terminal interprets commands as if these characters are are not there, even if they are put in the middle of a word/command

Comment: run `stty` in that terminal and see if there are any weird modes

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of it is weird. Here's the output:

speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?;
ixany iutf8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a wrong keyboard layout.
What do you have on `/etc/vconsole.conf`?
It's only on Arch or other distros also do it?

Comment: I've now added it to the original post. That file contains "KEYMAP=us"